# SNMP Manager like PRTG for OS X

Tags: osx, encryption, snmp

I want to be able to connect to a customer's site with my MBA and receive SNMP traffic. But haven't really been able to find a manager. I've used PRTG in the past, and have it loaded on a VM. but would really like something Native.

Is there an SNMP Manager like PRTG for OS X?

Right now I'm running El Capitan 10.11.6